# Installing A Custom Composer Package from GitLab

Tags: php, wordpress, git, composer-php

I've created a simple test wordpress plugin. The plugin consists of a single php file (kreplach.php) and a composer.json:

## kreplach.php

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: kreplach
    Plugin URI: http://gitlab.example.com/sales/kreplach
    Description: just a test
    Author: Foo Bartok
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://example.com
    */
?>
```

## composer.json

```
{
    "license": "MIT",
    "name": "sales/kreplach",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "description": "just a test",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Foo Bartok",
            "email": "foo@example.com",
            "homepage": "example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "*"
    }
}
```

On my dev server I have the following composer.json

## Server's composer.json

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.example.com:sales/kreplach.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "wpackagist-plugin/akismet": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/contact-form-7": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-importer": "*",
        "sales/kreplach": "master",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.*",
        "composer/installers": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "wordpress-install-dir": "wp"
    }
}
```

### What I think SHOULD happen:

1. Composer looks through the git repo for composer.json
2. Composer matches the name "sales/kreplach" found in the build host's composer.json
3. Composer copies the contents of the master branch into `wp-content/plugins/kreplach` on my build host.
4. My fake plug-in does nothing, as designed.

### What actually happens:

Bitter, bitter failure.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sales/kreplach could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
     see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have tested cloning the `sales/kreplach` repo onto the same host I'm attempting to install the plugin on.

To make sure that composer is actually reading the composer.json file from the git repo, I introduced a typo (yeah, totally on purpose, like) which threw a "hey, this json file is broken, Foam Head" error.

My version of gitlab is omnibus edition 8.6.4 (installed today).

I have successfully done this same sort of trick with pip/requirements.txt to install custom python modules, so I'm not unused to following directions. Am I missing a step, or some sort of non-obvious (to me at least) nomenclature?

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this? I get the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Update 2021, 5 years later, since [GitLab 13.3 (Aug. 2020)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/221259), GitLab (even in its free edition) has a [Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/), establishing GitLab as a private repository.

You can publish in it [Composer packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/), and, with [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#use-composer-v2-with-the-gitlab-package-registry) (April 2021):

> ### Use Composer v2 with the GitLab Package Registry
>
> You use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to publish, share, and download your PHP dependencies to your GitLab Project. Six months ago, a new major version (v2) of Composer was launched with a variety of changes, including significant performance improvements, architectural updates, and runtime features.
> You can read more about the changes [here](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-0-is-now-available/).
>
> Until recently, you couldn’t take advantage of these improvements because the GitLab registry didn’t support Composer v2.
> This prevented some of you from using the GitLab registry at all.
>
> As an MVC, we focused on adding support for the mandatory parameter `metadata-URL`. We added a new endpoint `GET group/:id/-/packages/composer/p2/:package_name`, which returns the metadata for all packages in your repository.
> When Composer looks for a package, it replaces `%package%` with the package name and fetches that URL.
>
> This means we’ve added a new endpoint `GET group/:id/-/packages/composer/p2/:package_name` which will return the metadata for all packages in your repository.
>
> Please note that there are two parameters considered optional.
> We have issues open to add support for the [`providers-api`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/324706) and [`list-api`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/324707) parameters. We hope to prioritize them in an upcoming milestone.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages/composer.html#v2-package-metadata) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/259840).

And (still [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#download-composer-dependencies-from-version-control), April 2021):

> ### Download Composer dependencies from version control
>
> You have two options when downloading Composer dependencies: `source` or `dist`. For stable versions, Composer uses `dist` by default and downloads the dependency as a `zip` file.
>
> However, you can also download it directly from version control.
> If `--prefer-source` is enabled, Composer downloads your dependency as a Git clone instead of as a packaged `zip` file.
>
> This is useful if you want to make a bug fix for a project and get a local Git clone of the dependency directly.
>
> Until recently, you could not use the `prefer-source` and related `preferred-install` commands and configurations when downloading Composer dependencies.
> This prevented many of you from using the GitLab Package Registry for your Composer dependencies.
>
> We are happy to announce that you can now download your Composer dependencies from source.
> Do so by simply adding the `prefer-source` option to your install command like this: `composer update --prefer-source`.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/#install-a-composer-package) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/247531).

Answer (score 0):

I've not used gitlab but have used this method quite a bit with Bitbucket and GitHub.

You need to specify `"sales/kreplach": "dev-master"` in the server's composer.json - note that the branch name must be prefixed with "dev-".

Apparently Composer has special support for GitHub and BitBucket, which may not exist for Gitlab...so you [may need to specify `git` as the repository type](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives) rather than `vcs`.

Good luck!

Refs:

- https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/use-a-github-branch-as-a-composer-dependency
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives